# Prove that the sequence is bounded above by $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$x_1=1$$  $$x_{n}=1+ \frac{x_{n-1} +5}{7}$$

Prove that the sequence is bounded above by $2$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use induction:

The base case is clear: $x_1=1 \le 2$.

Now, if $x_{n-1} \le 2$ then why do you have $x_n=1+\frac{x_{n-1}+5}{7} \le 2$?